# GCP stackdriver fo OnPrem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nagios, stackdriver

Based on Stackdriver, I want to send notifications to my Centreon monitoring (behind Nagios) for workflow reasons, do you have any idea on how to do so? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver alerting allows [webhook notifications](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks), so you can run a server to forward the notifications anywhere you need to (including Centreon), and point the Stackdriver alerting notification channel to that server.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to send external information in the Centreon queue without a traditional passive agent mode.

**First, you can use the Centreon DSM (Dynamic Services Management) addon**.
It is interesting because you don't have to register a dedicated and already known service in your configuration to match the notification.
With Centreon DSM, Centreon can receive events such as SNMP traps resulting from the detection of a problem and assign the event dynamically to a slot defined in Centreon, like a tray event.

A resource has a set number of “slots” on which alerts will be assigned (stored). While this event has not been taken into account by human action, it will remain visible in the Centreon web frontend. When the event is acknowledged, the slot becomes available for new events.

The event must be transmitted to the server via an SNMP Trap.

All the configuration is made through Centreon web interface after the module installation.
Complete explanations, screenshots, and tips are described on the online documentation: https://documentation.centreon.com/docs/centreon-dsm/en/latest/user.html

**Secondly, Centreon developers added a Centreon REST API** you can use to submit information to the monitoring engine.
This feature is easier to use than the SNMP Trap way.
In that case, you have to create both host/service objects before any API utilization.

To send status, please use the following URL using POST method:

```
api.domain.tld/centreon/api/index.php?action=submit&object=centreon_submit_results
```

*Header*

```
key value

Content-Type    application/json

centreon-auth-token the value of authToken you got on the authentication response
```

*Example of service body submit:* The body is a JSON with the parameters provided above formatted as below:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "updatetime": "1528884076",
      "host": "Centreon-Central"
      "service": "Memory",
      "status": "2"
      "output": "The service is in CRITICAL state"
      "perfdata": "perf=20"
    },
    {
      "updatetime": "1528884076",
      "host": "Centreon-Central"
      "service": "fake-service",
      "status": "1"
      "output": "The service is in WARNING state"
      "perfdata": "perf=10"
    }
  ]
}
```

*Example of body response:* :: The response body is a JSON with the HTTP return code, and a message for each submit:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "code": 202,
      "message": "The status send to the engine"
    },
    {
      "code": 404,
      "message": "The service is not present."
    }
  ]
}
```

More information is available in the online documentation: https://documentation.centreon.com/docs/centreon/en/19.04/api/api_rest/index.html

Centreon REST API also allows to get real-time status for hosts, services and do the object configuration.